# Updating Core Data with new data only

Tags: core-data

I have an online SQL database that needs to sync with my app's Core Data persistent store. Is there a simple way of writing to Core Data only data that currently does not exist?

For example:

If the SQL database currently holds 3 records: A B and C.

Core Data currently holds only A and B.

I just want to add C to Core Data during the syncing process.

I could do a series of loops to check each record but is there an easier way? All the records will be unique and therefore maybe there is a method for setting the Core Data attribute to act like a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Give the online database records a "last updated" attribute. Keep track of when your Core Data store was last updated. When it's time to sync, process only the remote records changed since your last local update.

Looping through all records, using find-or-create in Core Data, will be slow, because you'll be creating an `NSManagedObject` instance for each object in your datastore. Keep the logic needed for sync-or-not outside of Core Data for speed.